# VBA Code Performance Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a VBA macro to insert a column whereby it searches for a text character in column A. 
My code runs correctly. However, the file appears like it is going to crash. I will be building on the macro and want it to run smoothly.
Is there a way to optimise my code

Code:

```
Sheets("Annual Rec").Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=ISTEXT(RC[-1])"
Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Try to [Avoid Select/Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: You can start by removing your 3 x `Select` and 4 x `Selection`

Comment: And change your `Copy`/`Paste` to `Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value = Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below does the same as yours, just without the unnecessary `Select` and `Selection`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColPasteVal()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Annual Rec")
    .Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "General"
    With .Range("B2:B" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=ISTEXT(RC[-1])"
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Now add in something to say that `.Copy` `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` is equivalent to `.Value = .Value` ;)

Comment: @YowE3K  going to take a nap, I'll let you upgrade my answer if you feel like it ;)

Comment: I'm going to sleep for the night, no short nap breaks for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'your code
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

And avoid *Select* statements, they are quite slow.